# Mostrar información del elemento seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo `divs` con enlaces, al presionar un `div` me aparece la información de todos y solo quiero que aparezca la información del seleccionado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contenedor').click(function(){
       $('#test .contenedor a').each(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log("El resultado es: " + link);    
       });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="test">
    <div class="contenedor">
        <a href="mi_enlace_1.html">Opcion 1</a>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor">    
        <a href="mi_enlace_2.html">Opcion 2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor">
        <a href="mi_enlace_3.html">Opcion 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.contenedor').click(function() {
    $('#test .contenedor a').each(function() {
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log("El resultado es: " + link);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
votar en contra favorito

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<div id="test">
  <div class="contenedor">
    <a href="mi_enlace_1.html">Opcion 1</a>
  </div>

  <div class="contenedor">
    <a href="mi_enlace_2.html">Opcion 2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="contenedor">
    <a href="mi_enlace_3.html">Opcion 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba no usando `each()`. Tan solo busca un `<a>` dentro del elemento y obtén su `href`. Recuerda usar `preventDefault()` si no quieres que el link te redireccione.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contenedor').click(function(){
        var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        console.log("El resultado es: " + link);
    });
});
```

```css
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
#blue a {
  color: white;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
    <div id="yellow" class="contenedor">
        <a href="mi_enlace_1.html">Opcion 1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="blue" class="contenedor">    
        <a href="mi_enlace_2.html">Opcion 2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="red" class="contenedor">
        <a href="mi_enlace_3.html">Opcion 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```